# Supporting multiple instances of a plugin DLL with global data

Tags: c, windows, dll, pinvoke, ipc

Context: I converted a legacy standalone engine into a plugin component for a composition tool. Technically, this means that I compiled the engine code base to a C DLL which I invoke from a .NET wrapper using P/Invoke; the wrapper implements an interface defined by the composition tool. This works quite well, but now I receive the request to load multiple instances of the engine, for different projects. Since the engine keeps the project data in a set of global variables, and since the DLL with the engine code base is loaded only once, loading multiple projects means that the project data is overwritten.

I can see a number of solutions, but they all have some disadvantages:

1. You can create multiple DLLs with the same code, which are seen as different DLLs by Windows, so their code is not shared. Probably this already works if you have multiple copies of the engine DLL with different names. However, the engine is invoked from the wrapper using `DllImport` attributes and I think the name of the engine DLL needs to be known when compiling the wrapper. Obviously, if I have to compile different versions of the wrapper for each project, this is quite cumbersome.
2. The engine could run as a separate process. This means that the wrapper would launch a separate process for the engine when it loads a project, and it would use some form of IPC to communicate with this process. While this is a relatively clean solution, it requires some effort to get working, I don't now which IPC technology would be best to set-up this kind of construction. There may also be a significant overhead of the communication: the engine needs to frequently exchange arrays of floating-point numbers.
3. The engine could be adapted to support multiple projects. This means that the global variables should be put into a project structure, and every reference to the globals should be converted to a corresponding reference that is relative to a particular project. There are about 20-30 global variables, but as you can imagine, these global variables are referenced from all over the code base, so this conversion would need to be done in some automatic manner. A related problem is that you should be able to reference the "current" project structure in all places, but passing this along as an extra argument in each and every function signature is also cumbersome. Does there exist a technique (in C) to consider the current call stack and find the nearest enclosing instance of a relevant data value there?

Can the stackoverflow community give some advice on these (or other) solutions?

Comment: Is there no way to modify the engine DLL so that it has a factory method to return a "global" state on request?  E.g, wrap up everything that is currently global in to an object that can be created, thereby allowing multiple engines to be instantiated from a single DLL?

Comment: If anyone ever needed a reason why global variables are a bad idea, point them to this question.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: I think this would correspond to solution #3?

Comment: @Brune De Fraine, yes it does.  As Timbo points out, it's a pain in the ass but once you've done the legwork, it'll be worth it than trying to do something else.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've done this kind of thing before. Trust me, the preprocessor is your friend in these situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I received a lot of answers that suggested to go for solution 3, and although I agree it's a better solution *conceptually*, I think there was no way to realize that solution *practically* and *reliably* under my constraints.

Instead, what I actually implemented was a variation of solution #1. Although the DLL name in `DLLImport` needs to be a compile-time constant, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818011/set-dllimport-attribute-dynamically) explains how to do it dynamically.

If my code before looked like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class DotNetAccess {
    [DllImport("mylib.dll", EntryPoint="GetVersion")]
    private static extern int _getVersion();

    public int GetVersion()
    {
        return _getVersion();
        //May include error handling
    }
}
```

It now looks like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly;

class DotNetAccess: IDisposable {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="LoadLibrary", SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern IntPtr _loadLibrary(string name);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool _freeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="GetProcAddress", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern IntPtr _getProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string name);

    private static IntPtr LoadLibrary(string name)
    {
        IntPtr dllHandle = _loadLibrary(name);
        if (dllHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return dllHandle;
    }

    private static void FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule)
    {
        if (!_freeLibrary(hModule))
            throw new Win32Exception();
    }

    private static D GetProcEntryDelegate<D>(IntPtr hModule, string name)
        where D: class
    {
        IntPtr addr = _getProcAddress(hModule, name);
        if (addr == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addr, typeof(D)) as D;
    }

    private string dllPath;
    private IntPtr dllHandle;

    public DotNetAccess()
    {
        string dllDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location);
        string origDllPath = Path.Combine(dllDir, "mylib.dll");
        if (!File.Exists(origDllPath))
            throw new Exception("MyLib DLL not found");

        string myDllPath = Path.Combine(dllDir, String.Format("mylib-{0}.dll", GetHashCode()));
        File.Copy(origDllPath, myDllPath);
        dllPath = myDllPath;

        dllHandle = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
        _getVersion = GetProcEntryDelegate<_getVersionDelegate>(dllHandle, "GetVersion");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (dllHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            FreeLibrary(dllHandle);
            dllHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        if (dllPath != null)
        {
            File.Delete(dllPath);
            dllPath = null;
        }
    }

    private delegate int _getVersionDelegate();
    private readonly _getVersionDelegate _getVersion;

    public int GetVersion()
    {
        return _getVersion();
        //May include error handling
    }

}
```

Phew.

This may seem extremely complex if you see the two versions next to each other, but once you've set up the infrastructure, it is a very systematic change. And more importantly, it localizes the modification in my `DotNetAccess` layer, which means that I don't have to do modifications scattered all over a very large code base that is not my own.

Answer (score 6):

Put the whole darn thing inside a C++ class, then references to variables will automatically find the instance variable.

You can make a global pointer to the active instance.  This should probably be thread-local (see `__declspec(thread)`).

Add `extern "C"` wrapper functions that delegate to the corresponding member function on the active instance.  Provide functions to create new instance, teardown existing instance, and set the active instance.

OpenGL uses this paradigm to great effect (see `wglMakeCurrent`), finding its state data without actually having to pass a state pointer to every function.

Comment: +1. this sounds as a solution. of course project size should be big enough, in opposite case adding straightforward multi-instance support to the engine can be simpler (and better in long perspective)

Comment: Some problems with this solution: how can I put things from several files (compilation units) in one C++ class? Also, C++ members sometimes have vastly different semantics than C: e.g. static functions.

Comment: @Bruno: You'd have to #include everything into a single compilation unit.  And if you have static members with non-unique names you're going to have to fix those first.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, solution 3 is the way to go.

The disadvantage that you have to touch every call to the DLL should apply to the other solutions, too... without the lack of scalability and uglyness of the multiple-DLL approach and the unnecessary overhead of IPC.

Comment: Conceptually, this is the best solution, because that is what the legacy engine should have done from the start. But do you have any suggestion on how to automatically convert an existing code base?

Comment: I would just change the header files, compile the whole thing and then press F4 (goto next error) until it compiles again, but I guess you are looking for something more automated. Find+replace with regex might work, but I personally wouldn't trust that unless the change is super-simple.

Comment: yes, it would need to be more automated. It's not that I can make the change to the engine once and be done with it: the upstream will release new versions in the future and then I need to update my plugin version as well.

Comment: @Bruno Wait, this project you depend on is still maintained, but the creator doesn't want to implement multi-instance support? Maybe you should look for alternatives here :/

Answer (score 1):

Solution 3 IS the way to go.

Imagine, that current object oriented programming languages work similar to your 3rd solution, but only implicitly pass the pointer to the structure that contains the data of "this".

Passing around "some kind of context thing" is not cumbersome, but it is just how things work! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use approach #3. Since the code is in C, an easy way to deal with the globals that are spread everywhere is to define a macro for each global that has the same name as the global variable, but the macro expands to something like getSession()->theGlobal where getSession() returns a pinter to a "session-specific" structure that holds all the data for your globals. getSession() would fish the right data structure out of a global map of data structures somehow, perhaps using thread-local storage, or based on process ID, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually solution 3 is easier than it sounds. All other solutions are kind of patch and will break with time.

- Create a .net class which will encapsulate all access to the legacy code. Make it IDisposable.
- Change all the global variables to reside in a class named 'Context'
- Have all the C++ interfaces get the context object and pass it around as the first argument. This is probably the longest stage and you can avoid it using the "thread-local-storage" method suggested by someone else, but I would vote against that solution: if your library has any working threads which it runs, the "thread-local-storage" solution will break. Just add the context object where it is needed.
- Use the context object to access all global data.
- Have the context object created from .net ctor (by p/invoking a new create_context function) and deleted by the .net Dispose() method.

Enjoy.

Comment: The problem is definitely step #3: The global variables are used all over the code base; I would have to change the signature of almost every function in the code base to include the context object/structure as a first argument. That's a huge endeavor.

Comment: If the code is not thread-related, go with the "thread-local-storage" solution. But that solution won't work if your library create internal worker threads, for example.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my suggestion about thread-local storage.  I didn't suggest making all data thread-local, but the single context pointer (which saves passing it as an argument).  Multiple threads could still point to the same context, and parameter-passing could be used for e.g. callbacks which need to operate on an object other than the "current" one.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on suggested solution #2 (and a bit on #1 and #3).

1. Some sort of IPC layer might introduce lagging. It depends on the actual engine how bad that is. If the engine is a rendering engine and it is called, say, 60 times a second the overhead might be too much. But, if not, a named pipe might be quick enough and easy to create using WCF.
2. Are you entirely sure you will need EXACTLY the same engine multiple times or are you in danger of changing requirements that might lead to a scenario that forces your toward loading multiple versions at the same time? If so, option #2 might be a better way than option #3 as it would allow this easier.
3. If the IPC layer is not slowing things down too much, this architecture might allow you to distribute the engines over other PC's. This might enable you to use more hardware than you previously planned for. You could even think about hosting the engine in the Azure cloud.