# Loading multiple instance of DLL (C#/.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am developing C#/.NET 3.5 application. I am using legacy dll written in C, signals.dll. I invoke it from a .NET wrapper using P/Invoke. I am calling 2 types of processing functions, type A and B. When I call only one type of processing, all works fine. When I interleave calls to A and B processing, data result is corrupted. I believe that dll, signals.dll is using C style global variables, and data gets corrupted.

To resolve that, I created 2 copies of dll on disk, signals.dll and signals2.dll. Then I modified .NET wrapper using P/Invoke to direct type A processing to one dll, type B processing to another instance. And now, all works fine.

Then I saw similar problem on forums and solution there. ([Supporting multiple instances of a plugin DLL with global data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645558/supporting-multiple-instances-of-a-plugin-dll-with-global-data) ).
Basically, that proposed solution is dynamic lay from code, creating a new instance of .dll on disk (based on need), and loads it and invokes functions from it. Key part of code looks like this:

```
private IntPtr dllHandle;
string myDllPath = Path.Combine(dllDir, String.Format("mylib-{0}.dll", GetHashCode()));
        File.Copy(origDllPath, myDllPath);
        dllPath = myDllPath;
        dllHandle = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
        _getVersion = GetProcEntryDelegate<_getVersionDelegate>(dllHandle, "GetVersion");

    private delegate int _getVersionDelegate();
    private readonly _getVersionDelegate _getVersion;

public int GetVersion()
    {
        return _getVersion();
    }

private static D GetProcEntryDelegate<D>(IntPtr hModule, string name)
        where D: class
    {
        IntPtr addr = _getProcAddress(hModule, name);
        if (addr == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addr, typeof(D)) as D;
    }
```

What is coming to my mind, would it be possible to modify above code to create copy of dll IN MEMORY, not on disk and load it from there. I think just that IntPtr dllHandle needs to be fooled into getting value from memory, not from LoadLibrary. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Both [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requires a file path. You'll need a custom loading procedure, including memory mappings and what-not. I've found a [blog post ("Loading a DLL from memory")](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/) describing the procedure, and a matching GitHub project; [MemoryModule](https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule).

Comment: Thanks. That looks like something that is wanted. Is there an easy way to do that from C#?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing `just` about it :) - it's far more complex and involving

Here is a link that might help - [Load Library/Module from Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158846/load-library-module-from-memory)

And as @Hans Passant said I'd discourage you to go that way - even though it may be a tempting solution for some scenarios (but I don't see that you really need that honestly, nice maybe).

It involves dealing with the [portable executable format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#.NET.2C_metadata.2C_and_the_PE_format) - and I doubt that project covers all that needs to be done.

You could try making your C++/CLI wrapper - or exporting the `MemoryLoadLibrary` and try P/Invoking - but I doubt that'd work easily.