# DllImport and Instantiation

Tags: c#, interop, dllimport, instantiation

I am newbie in c# and I would apprentice if you could please help me to solve my problem.

I have an un-managed dll which I wrote the following wrapper class to access to its members.

```
unsafe public class EpaNet:IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            EpaNet.ENclose();
        }

        [DllImport("epanet2.dll")]
        public static extern int ENepanet(string Inputfile, string ReportFile, string OutputFile,byte[] N );

        [DllImport("epanet2.dll")]
        public static extern int ENopen(string Inputfile, string Reportfile, string Outputfile);

        some other functions ....
}
```

and to use this class I just write

```
EpaNet.ENopen(...)
```

This will give me access to the dll members.
and when I am running my code in single thread this wrapper works fine.
The problem begins when I wanna have more than one instance of this dll to run in parallel mode.
since all the members are static therefore in sequential mode I don't need to instantiate but for parallel mode I have to have various instance of this class each working with separate data file and I don't know how to do it.

so the question is how to create various instance of EpaNet class?

Regards,

e

Comment: Why do you have a `Dispose` method when you don't implement `IDisposable`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is a duplicate of [Loading multiple instance of DLL (C#/.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997037/loading-multiple-instance-of-dll-c-net)

Try to load epanet2.dll from memory. There's code for it on Github: https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule