# Loading multiple instances of a Dll in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

We have a piece of software that is used internally that has been turned into a Dll. It's written in C++. The desire was to run this on multiple platforms (Mac/Linux/Windows) as a service on the local network. There are 3 versions of this Dll: one for Mac, one for Linux and one for Windows. I've written a basic ASP.NET Core Web API that exposes the underlying functionality of the Dll via P/Invoke and a RESTful interface (my first), and I'm also in the process of writing a WPF client to pair with this new Web API service. The problem I have is that the Dll that was written is making heavy use of global data (arrays, variables, etc.) Therefore, if two or more clients are using the web API they will collide with the Dll's global state data. What I need is a way for each client to somehow load its own instance of the Dll.

After hunting around over the weekend I've discovered that this seems to be a pretty common problem and the standard "fix" is to dynamically make copies of the Dll file into a new file path and load it from there at runtime, for example:  [Loading multiple instance of DLL (C#/.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997037/loading-multiple-instance-of-dll-c-net)  Is a anyone aware of a better way of getting multiple "instances" of a Dll into memory in ASP.NET Core other than dynamically copying/loading from the file system, or is this still the only reasonable way to do this? If this is still the only way will this hack also work for Mac and Linux environments?

Comment: The best solution is to repay for your sins and refactor your C++ libraries and make them thread safe. Not sure about unmanaged dlls, but for managed dlls/assemblies there is a limitation: You can't unload a once loaded assembly, so effectively you have a memory leak when you keep loading a new dll for each request. In full .NET Framework you could workaround this by creating new AppDomain and loading your DLLs there and then unload this AppDomain once you don't need it anymore. But this concept is gone in .NET Core. So if you wanna use it you are limited to ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework

Comment: Thanks Tseng. Not the answer I wanted to hear, but it seems to be the correct answer nonetheless.