# How to Load different C++ dll in C# in function of a variable?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a UI in C# that loads a C++ Dll which contains the code of some process.
So the C# has an interface to communicate with the C++ dll using DllImport.

Now I would like to use the same C# UI but with a different C++ Dll which will have the same function call but totally different process inside.
So basically, in function of some parameters, my UI will load one or the other C++ DLL.
I have tried to create a string variable containing the name of the dll but it doesn't work.

I know I could create a c++ dll which could do the interface between the c++ and the c# code and could load one or the other c++ dll but if it is possible to do it without introducing a new dll, that would be better.

Do you know if there is a way to do that?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You might find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2818948/2609288

Comment: It doesn't seem that simple. So maybe I better create a c++ interface that can load one or the other dll.