# Using a dynamically loaded dll that contains a dynamically loaded dll itself

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, plugins

**Intro**

My program allows other developers to write plugins. These plugins(which are dll files) are placed in a certain directory and my program is able to load them at runtime like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyPluginPath");
object Plugin = assembly.CreateInstance("Plugins.Main", true);
```

Then the program will be able to call the `main` method from the plugin this way:

```
var pluginType = Plugin.GetType();
var methodOutput = pluginType.GetMethod("MyInternalMethod").Invoke(Plugin, new object[] {param});
```

This works fine for all the plugins I've wrote so far that followed a certain structure as below:

```
namespace Plugins
{
    public class Main : IDisposable
    {
        public Bitmap MyInternalMethod(Bitmap param)
        {
             // method body
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

Now there is this new plugin I've to wrote which loads an external dll at runtime itself:

```
namespace Plugins
{
    public class Main : IDisposable
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("MyExternalDLL.dll")]
        unsafe private static extern int Initialize(int* arg1, char* arg2);

        public Bitmap MyInternalMethod(Bitmap param)
        {
             // method body
             Initialize(x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

`Initialize(x,y)` method in the above code gives me an error that says

> Failed to initialize com library.

**Notes**

1. I created an executable test application for my plugin and it worked fine, so I know the problem occurs when using it as a dll at runtime.
2. I thought maybe I should load my external dll in the main program and then pass it as a `Func<>` object to my plugin but `Func<>` doesn't allow pointer variables (`Initialize` method contains arguments like `int*` and `char*`) and even if it does, I'm not sure if this solution is gonna work.
3. I tried using `winApi` as "Sinatr" suggested in the comments by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818948/1648849) answer but the error stays. I even tried loading `MyExternalDLL.dll` in the main program using `winApi` and passing the retrieved address of `Initialize` method to my plugin like the following code but the error remains the same (this way the error happens on `func(x,y)`):

*Main program:*

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string name);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string name);

    IntPtr dllHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr addr = IntPtr.Zero;

    private void RunPlugin()
    {
        dllHandle = LoadLibrary("MyExternalDLL.dll");
        addr = GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "Initialize");
        var methodOutput = pluginType.GetMethod("MyInternalMethod").Invoke(Plugin, new object[] {param, addr});
    }
```

*Plugin:*

```
    public class Main : IDisposable
    {
        private unsafe delegate byte initialize_api(int* arg1, char* arg2);

        public Bitmap MyInternalMethod(Bitmap param, IntPtr addr)
        {
            // method body
            //initialize_api is a delegate with the same signature as Initialize(x,y); 
            var func = (initialize_api)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addr, typeof(initialize_api));
            func(x,y);
        }
    }
```

4. Since we are talking about plugins here, I don't think implementing a common `Interface` which both my program and the plugins can use is possible.

**Question**

Is it even possible to use a dynamically loaded dll that contains a dynamically loaded dll the way I described? if it is, what should I do to make this work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you use MEF?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin I've never heard of it, I'm checking it out now however my main program is kinda big and it already uses many plugins. If I'm gonna use MEF, do I have to change many major parts of my application?

Comment: You can try to use winapi to load `myExternalDLL.dll` **dynamically** in plugin itself, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2818948/1997232) answer. You will have to provide plugin init/deinit methods, where dlls are loaded.

Comment: You would have to add some code in your main application for your plugins mapping, and add some attributes in your plugins so yes, there would be some changes, that could be major. This is a bit off-topic though, so let me just give you a good [MEF tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF) in case you want to try it. Good luck.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin, thanks for your response and also the link.

Comment: @Sinatr, the link you provided is similar to my issue somehow, I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sinatr: I've tried using winapi in two different ways (1- in the main program and 2- in the plugin). `myExternalDLL.dll's` handle and address are retrieved correctly in both ways but the error I mentioned stayed. Therefore I don't think using `winapi` instead of  using `DllImport("MyExternalDLL.dll")` directly makes any difference in my case.