# C# deezer native api: adapting to C#

Tags: c#, native, wrapper, deezer

I'm trying to use a C# class that wraps C++ native api into CLI C# class.
It seems that there are some problems (it really near to be working) and would like some help to find the problem.

Here is the wrapper's code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// make this binding dependent on WPF, but easier to use
using System.Windows.Threading;

// http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339290/PInvoke-pointer-safety-Replacing-IntPtr-with-unsaf

namespace Deezer
{

    #region Enums

    public enum CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE
    {
        UNKNOWN,                           /**< Connect event has not been set yet, not a valid value. */
        USER_OFFLINE_AVAILABLE,            /**< User logged in, and credentials from offline store are loaded. */

        USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_OK,              /**< (Not available) dz_connect_login_with_email() ok, and access_token is available */
        USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_FAILED,          /**< (Not available) dz_connect_login_with_email() failed */

        USER_LOGIN_OK,                     /**< Login with access_token ok, infos from user available. */
        USER_LOGIN_FAIL_NETWORK_ERROR,     /**< Login with access_token failed because of network condition. */
        USER_LOGIN_FAIL_BAD_CREDENTIALS,   /**< Login with access_token failed because of bad credentials. */
        USER_LOGIN_FAIL_USER_INFO,         /**< Login with access_token failed because of other problem. */
        USER_LOGIN_FAIL_OFFLINE_MODE,      /**< Login with access_token failed because we are in forced offline mode. */

        USER_NEW_OPTIONS,                  /**< User options have just changed. */

        ADVERTISEMENT_START,               /**< A new advertisement needs to be displayed. */
        ADVERTISEMENT_STOP,                /**< An advertisement needs to be stopped. */
    };

    public enum PLAYER_COMMANDS
    {
        UNKNOWN,           /**< Player command has not been set yet, not a valid value. */
        START_TRACKLIST,   /**< A new tracklist was loaded and a track played. */
        JUMP_IN_TRACKLIST, /**< The user jump into a new song in the current tracklist. */
        NEXT,              /**< Next button. */
        PREV,              /**< Prev button. */
        DISLIKE,           /**< Dislike button. */
        NATURAL_END,       /**< Natural end. */
        RESUMED_AFTER_ADS, /**< Reload after playing an ads. */
    }

    public enum TRACKLIST_AUTOPLAY_MODE
    {
        MODE_UNKNOWN,

        MANUAL,

        MODE_ONE,

        MODE_ONE_REPEAT,

        MODE_NEXT,

        MODE_NEXT_REPEAT,

        MODE_RANDOM,

        MODE_RANDOM_REPEAT,
    };

    public enum PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE
    {
        UNKNOWN,                             /**< Player event has not been set yet, not a valid value. */

        // Data access related event.
        LIMITATION_FORCED_PAUSE,             /**< Another deezer player session was created elsewhere, the player has entered pause mode. */

        // Track selection related event.
        PLAYLIST_TRACK_NOT_AVAILABLE_OFFLINE,/**< You're offline, the track is not available. */
        PLAYLIST_TRACK_NO_RIGHT,             /**< You don't have the right to render this track. */
        PLAYLIST_TRACK_RIGHTS_AFTER_AUDIOADS,/**< You have right to play it, but you should render an ads first :
                                              - Use dz_player_event_get_advertisement_infos_json().
                                              - Play an ad with dz_player_play_audioads().
                                              - Wait for #DZ_PLAYER_EVENT_RENDER_TRACK_END.
                                              - Use dz_player_play() with previous track or DZ_PLAYER_PLAY_CMD_RESUMED_AFTER_ADS (to be done even on radios for now).
                                          */
        PLAYLIST_SKIP_NO_RIGHT,              /**< You're on a radio, and you had no right to do skip. */

        PLAYLIST_TRACK_SELECTED,             /**< A track is selected among the ones available on the server, and will be fetched and read. */

        PLAYLIST_NEED_NATURAL_NEXT,          /**< We need a new natural_next action. */

        // Data loading related event.
        MEDIASTREAM_DATA_READY,              /**< Data is ready to be introduced into audio output (first data after a play). */
        MEDIASTREAM_DATA_READY_AFTER_SEEK,   /**< Data is ready to be introduced into audio output (first data after a seek). */

        // Play (audio rendering on output) related event.
        RENDER_TRACK_START_FAILURE,       /**< Error, track is unable to play. */
        RENDER_TRACK_START,               /**< A track has started to play. */
        RENDER_TRACK_END,                 /**< A track has stopped because the stream has ended. */
        RENDER_TRACK_PAUSED,              /**< Currently on paused. */
        RENDER_TRACK_SEEKING,             /**< Waiting for new data on seek. */
        RENDER_TRACK_UNDERFLOW,           /**< Underflow happened whilst playing a track. */
        RENDER_TRACK_RESUMED,             /**< Player resumed play after a underflow or a pause. */
        RENDER_TRACK_REMOVED,             /**< Player stopped playing a track. */
    };

    #endregion

    #region Delegates

    // called with userdata Dispatcher on connect events
    public delegate void ConnectOnEventCb(Connect connect, ConnectEvent connectEvent, DispatcherObject userdata);
    public delegate void PlayerOnEventCb(Player player, PlayerEvent playerEvent, DispatcherObject userdata);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    unsafe public delegate void libcConnectOnEventCb(CONNECT* libcConnect, CONNECT_EVENT* libcConnectEvent, IntPtr userdata);
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    unsafe public delegate bool libcAppCrashDelegate();
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    unsafe public delegate void libcPlayerOnEventCb(PLAYER* libcPlayer, PLAYER_EVENT* libcPlayerEvent, IntPtr userdata);

    #endregion

    #region Structures

    unsafe public struct CONNECT_EVENT { };

    unsafe public struct UTF8STRING { };

    unsafe public struct CONNECT { };

    unsafe public struct PLAYER_EVENT { };

    unsafe public struct PLAYER { };

    #endregion

    #region Imports

    #endregion

    // to be in sync with dz_connect_configuration
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class ConnectConfig
    {
        public string ccAppId;
        public string ccAppSecret;

        public string ccUserProfilePath;

        public Dispatcher ccConnectUserdata;
        public ConnectOnEventCb ccConnectEventCb;
    }

    public class ConnectEvent
    {
        internal CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE eventType;

        /* two design strategies:
         * - we could keep a reference to CONNECT_EVENT* with dz_object_retain and call method on the fly
         * - we extract all info in constructor and have pure managed object
         * 
         * here we keep the second option, because we have to have a managed object anyway, and it's 
         * a lot fewer unsafe method to expose, even though it's making a lot of calls in the constructor..
         */
        public unsafe static ConnectEvent newFromLibcEvent(CONNECT_EVENT* libcConnectEventHndl)
        {
            CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE eventType;
            unsafe
            {
                eventType = dz_connect_event_get_type(libcConnectEventHndl);
            }
            switch (eventType)
            {
                case CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE.USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_OK:
                    string accessToken;
                    unsafe
                    {
                        IntPtr libcAccessTokenString = dz_connect_event_get_access_token(libcConnectEventHndl);
                        accessToken = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(libcAccessTokenString);
                    }
                    return new NewAccessTokenConnectEvent(accessToken);
                default:
                    return new ConnectEvent(eventType);
            }
        }

        public ConnectEvent(CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE eventType)
        {
            this.eventType = eventType;
        }

        public CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE GetEventType()
        {
            return eventType;
        }

        [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern unsafe CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE dz_connect_event_get_type(CONNECT_EVENT* dzConnectEvent);

        [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern unsafe IntPtr dz_connect_event_get_access_token(CONNECT_EVENT* dzConnectEvent);
    }

    public class NewAccessTokenConnectEvent : ConnectEvent
{
    string accessToken;

    public NewAccessTokenConnectEvent(string accessToken)
        : base(CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE.USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_OK)
    {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public string GetAccessToken()
    {
        return accessToken;
    }
}

    unsafe public class Connect
{
    // hash
    static Hashtable refKeeper = new Hashtable();

    internal unsafe CONNECT* libcConnectHndl;
    internal ConnectConfig connectConfig;

    public unsafe Connect(ConnectConfig cc)
    {
        NativeMethods.LoadClass();
        //ConsoleHelper.AllocConsole();
        // attach a console to parent process (launch from cmd.exe)
        //ConsoleHelper.AttachConsole(-1);

        CONNECT_CONFIG libcCc = new CONNECT_CONFIG();

        connectConfig = cc;

        IntPtr intptr = new IntPtr(this.GetHashCode());

        refKeeper[intptr] = this;

        libcCc.ccAppId = cc.ccAppId;
        //libcCc.ccAppSecret = cc.ccAppSecret;

        libcCc.ccUserProfilePath = UTF8Marshaler.GetInstance(null).MarshalManagedToNative(cc.ccUserProfilePath);
        libcCc.ccConnectEventCb = delegate (CONNECT* libcConnect, CONNECT_EVENT* libcConnectEvent, IntPtr userdata)
        {
            Connect connect = (Connect)refKeeper[userdata];
            ConnectEvent connectEvent = ConnectEvent.newFromLibcEvent(libcConnectEvent);
            Dispatcher dispather = connect.connectConfig.ccConnectUserdata;

            dispather.Invoke(connect.connectConfig.ccConnectEventCb, connect, connectEvent, connect.connectConfig.ccConnectUserdata);
        };

        libcConnectHndl = dz_connect_new(libcCc);

        UTF8Marshaler.GetInstance(null).CleanUpNativeData(libcCc.ccUserProfilePath);
    }

    public int Start()
    {
        int ret;
        ret = dz_connect_activate(libcConnectHndl, new IntPtr(this.GetHashCode()));
        return ret;
    }

    public string DeviceId()
    {
        IntPtr libcDeviceId = dz_connect_get_device_id(libcConnectHndl);

        if (libcDeviceId == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(libcDeviceId);
    }

    public int SetAccessToken(string accessToken)
    {
        int ret;
        ret = dz_connect_set_access_token(libcConnectHndl, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, accessToken);
        return ret;
    }

    public int SetSmartCache(string path, int quotaKb)
    {
        int ret;
        ret = dz_connect_cache_path_set(libcConnectHndl, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, path);
        ret = dz_connect_smartcache_quota_set(libcConnectHndl, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, quotaKb);
        return ret;
    }

    [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern unsafe CONNECT* dz_connect_new(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        CONNECT_CONFIG lpcc);

    [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern unsafe IntPtr dz_connect_get_device_id(
        CONNECT* dzConnect);

    [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern unsafe int dz_connect_activate(
        CONNECT* dzConnect, IntPtr userdata);

    [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern unsafe int dz_connect_set_access_token(
        CONNECT* dzConnect, IntPtr cb, IntPtr userdata, string access_token);

    [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern unsafe int dz_connect_cache_path_set(
        CONNECT* dzConnect, IntPtr cb, IntPtr userdata,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler,
          MarshalTypeRef=typeof(UTF8Marshaler))]
          string local_path);

    [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern unsafe int dz_connect_smartcache_quota_set(
        CONNECT* dzConnect, IntPtr cb, IntPtr userdata,
          int quota_kB);
}

    public class PlayerEvent
    {
        internal PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE eventType;

        /* two design strategies:
         * - we could keep a reference to PLAYER_EVENT* with dz_object_retain and call method on the fly
         * - we extract all info in constructor and have pure managed object
         * 
         * here we keep the second option, because we have to have a managed object anyway, and it's 
         * a lot fewer unsafe method to expose, even though it's making a lot of calls in the constructor..
         */
        public unsafe static PlayerEvent newFromLibcEvent(PLAYER_EVENT* libcPlayerEventHndl)
        {
            PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE eventType;
            unsafe
            {
                eventType = dz_player_event_get_type(libcPlayerEventHndl);
            }
            switch (eventType)
            {
                default:
                    return new PlayerEvent(eventType);
            }
        }

        public PlayerEvent(PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE eventType)
        {
            this.eventType = eventType;
        }

        public PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE GetEventType()
        {
            return eventType;
        }

        [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern unsafe PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE dz_player_event_get_type(PLAYER_EVENT* dzPlayerEvent);
    }

    unsafe public class Player
    {
        // hash
        static Hashtable refKeeper = new Hashtable();

        internal unsafe PLAYER* libcPlayerHndl;
        internal Connect connect;
        internal libcPlayerOnEventCb eventcb;


        public unsafe Player(Connect connect, object observer)
        {
            IntPtr intptr = new IntPtr(this.GetHashCode());

            refKeeper[intptr] = this;

            libcPlayerHndl = dz_player_new(connect.libcConnectHndl);

            this.connect = connect;
        }

        public int Start(PlayerOnEventCb eventcb)
        {
            int ret;
            ret = dz_player_activate(libcPlayerHndl, new IntPtr(this.GetHashCode()));

            this.eventcb = delegate (PLAYER* libcPlayer, PLAYER_EVENT* libcPlayerEvent, IntPtr userdata)
            {
                Player player = (Player)refKeeper[userdata];
                PlayerEvent playerEvent = PlayerEvent.newFromLibcEvent(libcPlayerEvent);
                Dispatcher dispather = player.connect.connectConfig.ccConnectUserdata;

                dispather.Invoke(eventcb, player, playerEvent, connect.connectConfig.ccConnectUserdata);
            };

            ret = dz_player_set_event_cb(libcPlayerHndl, this.eventcb);
            return ret;
        }

        public int LoadStream(string url)
        {
            int ret;
            ret = dz_player_load(libcPlayerHndl, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, url);
            return ret;
        }

        public int Play(int idx, PLAYER_COMMANDS cmd)
        {
            int ret;
            ret = dz_player_play(libcPlayerHndl, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, cmd, TRACKLIST_AUTOPLAY_MODE.MODE_ONE, idx);
            return ret;
        }

        [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern unsafe PLAYER* dz_player_new(CONNECT* lpcc);
        //static extern unsafe PLAYER* dz_player_new(CONNECT* lpcc, IntPtr userdata);

        [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern unsafe int dz_player_set_event_cb(PLAYER* lpcc, libcPlayerOnEventCb cb);

        [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern unsafe int dz_player_activate(PLAYER* dzPlayer, IntPtr userdata);
        //static extern unsafe int dz_player_activate(PLAYER* dzPlayer, IntPtr userdata);

        [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern unsafe int dz_player_load(PLAYER* dzPlayer, IntPtr cb, IntPtr userdata, string url);

        [DllImport("libdeezer.x64.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern unsafe int dz_player_play(PLAYER* dzPlayer, IntPtr cb, IntPtr userdata, PLAYER_COMMANDS cmd, TRACKLIST_AUTOPLAY_MODE mode, int idx);
        //static extern unsafe int dz_player_play(PLAYER* dzPlayer, IntPtr cb, IntPtr userdata, int idx, TRACKLIST_AUTOPLAY_MODE mode);
    }



    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class CONNECT_CONFIG
    {
        public string ccAppId;

        public string ccProductId;
        public string ccProductBuildId;

        public IntPtr ccUserProfilePath;

        public libcConnectOnEventCb ccConnectEventCb;

        public string ccAnonymousBlob;

        public libcAppCrashDelegate ccAppCrashDelegate;

    }




    // trick from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573724/cpu-architecture-independent-p-invoke-can-the-dllname-or-path-be-dynamic
    // but actually SetDllDirectory works better (for pthread.dll)
    public static class NativeMethods
{
    // call this to load this class
    public static void LoadClass()
    {
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    static NativeMethods()
    {
        string arch;
        string basePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(NativeMethods).Assembly.Location);


        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            arch = "i386";
        else
            arch = "x86_64";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("using arch: " + arch);

        SetDllDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, arch));
#if false // can be used to debug library loading
        IntPtr hExe = LoadLibrary("libdeezer.x64.dll");

        if (hExe == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            System.Console.WriteLine("exception:" + ex);
            throw ex;
        }
#endif
    }

}

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415807/output-console-writeline-from-wpf-windows-applications-to-actual-console
    public class ConsoleHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allocates a new console for current process.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool AttachConsole(int processId);

    /// <summary>
    /// Frees the console.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean FreeConsole();
}

    // http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138614/Advanced-Topics-in-PInvoke-String-Marshaling
    public class UTF8Marshaler : ICustomMarshaler
{
    static UTF8Marshaler static_instance;

    // maybe we could play with WideCharToMultiByte too and avoid Marshal.Copy
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537573/how-to-get-intptr-from-byte-in-c-sharp
    /*
        Byte[] byNewData = null;

        iNewDataLen = NativeMethods.WideCharToMultiByte(NativeMethods.CP_UTF8, 0, cc.ccUserProfilePath, -1, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        Console.WriteLine("iNewDataLen:" + iNewDataLen + " len:" + cc.ccUserProfilePath.Length + " ulen:" + iNewDataLen);
        byNewData = new Byte[iNewDataLen];
        iNewDataLen = NativeMethods.WideCharToMultiByte(NativeMethods.CP_UTF8, 0, cc.ccUserProfilePath, cc.ccUserProfilePath.Length, byNewData, iNewDataLen, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        libcCc.ccUserProfilePath = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(byNewData, 0);
     */
    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object managedObj)
    {
        if (managedObj == null)
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        if (!(managedObj is string))
            throw new MarshalDirectiveException(
                   "UTF8Marshaler must be used on a string.");

        // not null terminated
        byte[] strbuf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)managedObj);
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(strbuf.Length + 1);
        Marshal.Copy(strbuf, 0, buffer, strbuf.Length);

        // write the terminating null
        Marshal.WriteByte(buffer + strbuf.Length, 0);
        return buffer;
    }
    public unsafe object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        byte* walk = (byte*)pNativeData;

        // find the end of the string
        while (*walk != 0)
        {
            walk++;
        }
        int length = (int)(walk - (byte*)pNativeData);

        // should not be null terminated
        byte[] strbuf = new byte[length];
        // skip the trailing null
        Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)pNativeData, strbuf, 0, length);
        string data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(strbuf);
        return data;
    }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNativeData);
    }

    public void CleanUpManagedData(object managedObj)
    {
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize()
    {
        return -1;
    }

    public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string cookie)
    {
        if (static_instance == null)
        {
            return static_instance = new UTF8Marshaler();
        }
        return static_instance;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int WideCharToMultiByte(uint CodePage, uint dwFlags,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpWideCharStr, int cchWideChar,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Byte[] lpMultiByteStr, int cbMultiByte, IntPtr lpDefaultChar,
       IntPtr lpUsedDefaultChar);

    public const uint CP_UTF8 = 65001;
}
}
```

And here is the caller method to play a song :

```
            ConnectConfig dConfig = new ConnectConfig();
            dConfig.ccAppId = appId;
            dConfig.ccAppSecret = appSecret;
            dConfig.ccConnectUserdata = this.Dispatcher;  
            dConfig.ccUserProfilePath = @"D:\devlocal\dztemp";

            Connect dConnect = new Connect(dConfig);
            dConnect.SetAccessToken(accesToken);
            //dConnect.SetSmartCache(@"D:\devlocal\dztemp", 2000000);
            CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE resp = (CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE)dConnect.Start();
            String devId = dConnect.DeviceId();

            Object dObserver = null;
            Player dPlayer = new Player(dConnect, dObserver);
            PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE respPlayerStart = (PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE)dPlayer.Start(dPlayerOnEventCb);
            PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE respPlayerLoad = (PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE)dPlayer.LoadStream("dzmedia:///track/97206076");
            PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE respPlayerPlay = (PLAYER_EVENT_TYPE)dPlayer.Play(0, PLAYER_COMMANDS.NEXT);
```

First lines seem to be working correctly but:

```
CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE resp = (CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE)dConnect.Start();
```

returns a bad value (always the first one of the enum).

```
String devId = dConnect.DeviceId();
```

is ok, I have my device token.

`dPlayer.Start`, `dPlayer.LoadStream`, `dPlayer.Play` are returning bad values and there is no sound playing.

Comment: another important thing i forgot to mention : When I launch this code, it says that it is unable to cast dispatcher to dispatcherobject.  I think it comes from dConfig.ccConnectUserdata = this.Dispatcher; line (I'm using a WPF application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are miscasting the returned value. Most of the functions return `dz_error_t` (you can find the enum values in *deezer-object.h*) the enum `CONNECT_EVENT_TYPE` is mapped on `dz_connect_event_t`.
I would suggest to create a new enum mapped on `dz_error_t` and cast with this new enum.

Moreover, as described in http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/native (Section **Playing a song**) for the moment only `DZ_TRACKLIST_AUTOPLAY_MANUAL` is supported. So I would suggest to change the `dz_player_play` call into:

```
dz_player_play(libcPlayerHndl, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, cmd, TRACKLIST_AUTOPLAY_MODE.MANUAL, idx);
```

and `dPlayer.Play` into:

```
dPlayer.Play(0, PLAYER_COMMANDS.START_TRACKLIST);
```

If you still have an issue, please also post the traces returned by your application.

Do you have files created in the path provided by `ccUserProfilePath` ?

If you still have an issue, be sure you have right to play the song by trying to play it with your Internet browser at this address http://www.deezer.com/track/97206076.

Regards,

Cyril

Comment: Thank you Cyril, I'll try when I get home.
Just another thing : what about dispatcher cast to dispatcherobject ?

Comment: Thank you Cyril,

There was some modifications to do like you said.
I created the errors enum, changed the calling code return types to this enum, also changed something I did : I replaced all Dispatcher types to DispatcherObject like it was before.   
I also changed the dispather.invoke calls to dispather.Dispatcher.invoke.  
into calling code, I set ccConnectUserdata property to "this". 
it seems to work but I have no sound.  
I just added a breakpoint into the dPlayerOnEventCb to see that there is a PLAYLIST_TRACK_NO_RIGHT. and I tested the track through web browser and its ok.

Comment: And I forgot :
I tried with another tracks, it's the same.
Also, I have nothing into my dztempt folder

Comment: Just opened another topic about that problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37229812/c-sharp-wrapper-for-c-deezer-library-playlist-track-no-right